# hadoop streaming don't untar archives

Tags: hadoop, streaming

when writing hadoop streaming task. i used -archives to upload a tgz from local machine to hdfs task working directory, but it has not been untarred as the document says. I've searched a lot without any luck.

Here is the hadoop streaming task starting command with hadoop-2.5.2, very simple

```
hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.5.2.jar \
    -files mapper.sh
    -archives /home/hadoop/tmp/test.tgz#test \
    -D mapreduce.job.maps=1 \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=1 \
    -input "/test/test.txt" \
    -output "/res/" \
    -mapper "sh mapper.sh" \
    -reducer "cat"
```

and "mapper.sh"

```
cat > /dev/null
ls -l test
exit 0
```

in "test.tgz" there is two files "test.1.txt" and "test.2.txt"

```
echo "abcd" > test.1.txt
echo "efgh" > test.2.txt
tar zcvf test.tgz test.1.txt test.2.txt
```

the output from above task

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hadoop hadoop     71 Feb  8 23:25 test -> /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/filecache/116/test.tgz
```

but what desired may be like this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 5 Feb  8 23:25 test.1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 5 Feb  8 23:25 test.2.txt
```

so, why test.tgz has not been untarred automatically as [document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html#Making_Archives_Available_to_Tasks) says, and is there any other way makes the "tgz" being untarred

any help please, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. After submitted a issue to hadoop.apache.org. I've been told that hadoop actually has already untarred the test.tgz.

Although the name is still test.tgz, but it's an after untarred direcotry. So the files can be read like "cat test/test.1.txt"

Answer (score 0):

This will untarred `tar -zxvf test.tgz`

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Comment: Actually i hope after "test.tgz" uploaded to hdfs along the starting of streaming task, It will be untarred automatically. as what the [document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-lient/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html#Making_Archives_Available_to_Tasks) says. "The -archives option allows you to copy jars locally to the current working directory of tasks and automatically unjar the files"